# Data from firestore wont load when routing, angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I have a frontend app with angular 6, im using **Firestore** of Firebase to store the data, the database contains a collection of **wells**.

I want to display the well information in **cards**, I created a card component. There is a **wellFirestore** service that handles the connection with the firestore, the card component was able to read the data from firebase and display it as a simple card, but when I **route out** from that page to another page then go back to the page with the card, the information **wont load**. Even the console logs in the card component dont log anything when routing back, but when I refresh the page all is fine again, until it route out.

Im new to Angular, and not quite sure how to debug this.any and all help in the matter would be welcome.

The **wellFirestore**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection , AngularFirestoreDocument  } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { importType } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';
import { Well } from '../models/well';
import { reading } from '../models/reading';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WellFirestore{
  items: Observable<Well[]>
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
      // this.items = this.afs.collection('Well-Nodes').valueChanges();
      this.items = this.afs.collection('Well-Nodes').snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(res => {
          return res.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Well;
            data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return data;
          });
        })
      )
   }

   getWells(){
     return this.items;
   }

   getWellById(wellID: string){
    return this.afs.collection('Well-Nodes').doc(wellID).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(res => {
        const data = res.payload.data() as Well;
        data.id = res.payload.id;
        return data;
      })
    );
   }

   getReadings(wellID: string){
     return this.afs.collection('Well-Nodes').doc(wellID).collection('Readings' , ref => ref.orderBy("Timestamp")).snapshotChanges().pipe(
       map(res => {
        return res.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as reading;
          data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return data;
        })
       })
     );
   }
}
```

The **Card component**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WellFirestore } from '../../services/well-firestore.service';
import { Well } from '../../models/well';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'card-comp',
  templateUrl: 'cards.component.html'
})
export class CardsComponent {

  wells: Well[];
  wellID: string;
  reading: number;
  volume: number;

  constructor(private wellDAO: FireUpService) {

    this.wellDAO.getWells().subscribe(item => {
      console.log(item);

      this.wells = item;   
      this.wellID = item.pop().id

      this.wellDAO.getReadings(this.wellID).subscribe(data =>{
        console.log(data);
        let levels = data.map(item => item.Level);
        let vol = data.map(item => item.Volume);
        console.log(levels);
        this.reading = levels.pop();
        this.volume = vol.pop();
      } );
    });
  }
}
```

The Routing Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// Import Containers
import { DefaultLayoutComponent } from './containers';

import { P404Component } from './views/error/404.component';
import { P500Component } from './views/error/500.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './views/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './views/register/register.component';


export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '404',
    component: P404Component,
    data: {
      title: 'Page 404'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '500',
    component: P500Component,
    data: {
      title: 'Page 500'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Login Page'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Register Page'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'base',
        loadChildren: './views/base/base.module#BaseModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'buttons',
        loadChildren: './views/buttons/buttons.module#ButtonsModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'charts',
        loadChildren: './views/chartjs/chartjs.module#ChartJSModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './views/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
      },
      {
        path: 'icons',
        loadChildren: './views/icons/icons.module#IconsModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'notifications',
        loadChildren: './views/notifications/notifications.module#NotificationsModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'theme',
        loadChildren: './views/theme/theme.module#ThemeModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'widgets',
        loadChildren: './views/widgets/widgets.module#WidgetsModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  providers: [

  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Could you provide your router module code ?

Comment: I Edited the question, im trying to modify the angular project of CoreUI dashboard.